# Generate sequence with unknown bound, based on condition

Tags: scala

I want to generate sequance of all fibonacci numbers, that less then 10000

For example, this will generate 40 fibonacci numbers. But i want to stop generate them with some condition. How can i do this?

```
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val fibonacciSequence = for(i <- 1 to 40) yield fibonacci(i) 
    println(fibonacciSequence)
  }

  def fibonacci(i: Int) : Int = i match {
    case 0 => 0
    case 1 => 1
    case _ => fibonacci(i - 1) + fibonacci(i - 2);
  }
```

I want something like this: for(i <- 1 to ?; stop if fibonacci(i) > 100000)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This method, involving lazy infinite collection calculation, could produce suitable result:

```
import scala.Numeric.Implicits._

def fibonacci[N: Numeric](a: N, b: N): Stream[N] = a #:: fibonacci(b, a + b)
```

so

```
fibonacci(0L,1L).takeWhile(_ < 1000L).toList
```

yields

```
List(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, 987)
```

If you don't want to use intermediate value to cache collection of proper type and init, you could just declare a `val` like this:

```
val fib: Stream[Long] = 0 #:: 1 #:: (fib zip fib.tail map { case (a, b) => a + b })
```

Answer (score 1):

Using iterators and memoization (computing the current result based in the latest ones, not recomputing what has already been done), (method from  [Rosetta](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fibonacci_sequence#Scala), similar to Odomontois's streams),

```
def fib() = Iterator.iterate((0,1)){ case (a,b) => (b,a+b)}.map(_._1)
```

To get the first *n*th values consider for instance,

```
def nfib(n: Int) = fib().zipWithIndex.takeWhile(_._2 < n).map(_._1).toArray
```

To get consecutive values up to a given condition or predicate,

```
def pfib(p: Int => Boolean) = fib().takeWhile(p).toArray
```

Thus, for example

```
nfib(10)
Array(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)

pfib( _ < 55)
Array(0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34)
```